# Automated path update from a scrolling list

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to edit automatically links of my excel sheet depending on a hotel name scrolling list.

So far, I have managed to create an automated path (see picture attached), yet I did not manage to update links as soon as the cell ("A1")(the scrolling list) is modified

[image: File name path]
This is what I have in mind for the Macro:

1. Memorize the previous path,
2. Replace it with the new path following the change of the Cell "A1"
3. Update

See my draft below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range(A1)

     If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
    Run Macro_2
    End If
End Sub

Sub Macro_2()

   Range("F2").Copy
    Range("F1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ChDir Dir(Range("F2").Value)
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=Dir(Range("F1").Value) _
        , NewName:=Dir(Range("F2").Value) _
        , Type:=xlExcelLinks

End Sub
```

> Error : Path not found

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: On which line of your code do you get the error? I would expect `Run Macro_2` to cause an error. Omit the "Run". You might say `Call Macro_2` but the "Call" is superfluous. `Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address))` shouldn't cause an error but it is convoluted. `Target` is already a range. Therefore `Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target)` will do the same job.

Comment: `ChDir` and `Dir` are two different commands. I suggest to test what `Dir(Range("F2").Value)` returns. You probably mean something like `ChDir Range("F2").Value` and continue to use the `Dir` function similarly wrong in the next instruction. The proper use of `Dir` is to check if the path exists and not to continue using that path if it doesn't.

Comment: the error comes on the Macro_2(), it does not recognize the ChDir Dir(Range("F2").value neither does it recognize the ChDir Range("F2").value.     Note that the Cell F2 contains the following: ="C:\Users\h5307-rm\Desktop\Casablanca\hotels\"&VLOOKUP($A$1,Setup!$A$2:$C$3,2,FALSE)&"\"&Sheet1!A1&"\Budget\[Budget.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1"

Comment: If you are going to add/modify/delete values on the same worksheet where you are running a Worksheet_Change event macro, temporarily suspend events with application.enableevents = false or the worksheet_change will try to run on top of itself. Remember to re-enable events with application.enableevents = true (typically through error control) before exiting the worksheet_change.

Comment: `Range(A1)` is wrong. At a minimum it should be `Range("A1")` but you essentially declare and set a range object only to create another range object using the originals string address. Seems like digging a hole so you can fill it up again.

Answer (score 0):

The values in F1 and F2 are not paths. A path must end before the file name and can't, of course, include a worksheet within that file and a cell address in that worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

this is your code rewritten (un-necessary code removed)

please read the comments in the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Application.Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Range("F2").Copy
    Range("F1").PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, _
        Transpose:=False

    ' this value is in F1 and in F2  ( it is NOT a valid filename )
    ' C:\Users\h5307-rm\Desktop\Casablanca\hotels\Casablanca\Ibis El Jadida\Budget\[Budget.xlsx]Sheet1'$A$1

    ' F2 contains an invalid path name ... ChDir command will fail
    ChDir Dir(Range("F2").Value)

    ' F1 and F2 contain invalid path names, this command will fail
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink _
        Name:=Dir(Range("F1").Value), _
        NewName:=Dir(Range("F2").Value), _
        Type:=xlExcelLinks

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How should I write the path + Filename to have a valid one ?

Comment: same way you made the invalid path in F2, but leave out the bad parts. you already know what the correct path should be (the file that you are processing is on your computer)